# Use of Proper data Structure

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I have developed a dictionary application with offline database support.Everything works fine for me but the application is taking time in retrieving the definition of the words.I know there is the problem with the data structure.I only knew the implementation of ArrayList but I do not know how to implement any other data structures(HashMap, TRIE or any other) in my application.I have tried the Oracle documentations for the same but all my efforts went in vain.I just want some help regarding how to implement HashMap or any other data structure in my application.

Thanks in advance...

DMainActivity.java

```
public class DMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText filterText;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

private TextView textView2;
private TextView textView3;
private TextView textView4;
private TextView textView5;
private TextView textView6;
private TextView textView7;
private TextView textView8;
private TextView textView9;
private TextView textView10;
private TextView textView11;
private TextView textView12;
private TextView textView13;
private TextView textView14;
private TextView textView15;
private TextView textView16;
private TextView textView17;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dmain);

    filterText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final ListView itemList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    itemList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textView5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    textView6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    textView7 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    textView8 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    textView9 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    textView10 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    textView11 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    textView12 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    textView13 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    textView14 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView14);
    textView15 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView15);
    textView16 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView16);
    textView17 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView17);


    final DbBackend dbBackend = new DbBackend(DMainActivity.this);
    String[] terms = dbBackend.dictionaryWords();
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_textview,R.id.tv, terms);

   // listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, terms);

    itemList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // make Toast when click
           String word = listAdapter.getItem(position);
            String[] words = dbBackend.dictionaryWords();

            for(int i=0; i < words.length; i++)
                if(words[i].contains(word))
                    position = i;

            Toast.makeText(DMainActivity.this, word + " " +position , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(DMainActivity.this, DictionaryActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("DICTIONARY_ID", position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //MainActivity.this.listAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s != null && s.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                itemList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //textView1.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                textView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView11.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView12.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView13.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView14.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView15.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView16.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView17.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {
                itemList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView13.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView14.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView15.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView16.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView17.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            listAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }


    });
}

}
```

DbBackend.java

```
public class DbBackend extends DbObject{

public DbBackend(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public String[] dictionaryWords(){
    String query = "Select * from words";
    Cursor cursor = this.getDbConnection().rawQuery(query, null);
    **ArrayList<String> wordTerms = new ArrayList<String>();
   // HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> hashMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();**
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("word"));
            wordTerms.add(word);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    String[] dictionaryWords = new String[wordTerms.size()];
    dictionaryWords = wordTerms.toArray(dictionaryWords);
    return dictionaryWords;
}

public QuizObject getQuizById(int quizId){

    QuizObject quizObject = null;
    String query = "select * from words where _id = " + quizId;
    Cursor cursor = this.getDbConnection().rawQuery(query, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("word"));
            String meaning = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("defn"));
            quizObject = new QuizObject(word, meaning);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return quizObject;
}
}
```

DictionaryActivity.java

```
public class DictionaryActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
private TextView wordMeaning;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dict_activity);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    int dictionaryId = bundle.getInt("DICTIONARY_ID");
    int id = dictionaryId + 1;

    TextView word = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.word);
    wordMeaning = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dictionary);
  //  Button textToSpeech = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    DbBackend dbBackend = new DbBackend(DictionaryActivity.this);
    QuizObject allQuizQuestions = dbBackend.getQuizById(id);

    word.setText(allQuizQuestions.getWord());
    wordMeaning.setText(allQuizQuestions.getDefinition());

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are interested to find the `id` of the words in your database (you call it `position`).  Therefore you should create a `Map` that maps a word to its `id`, this `Map` would look like:

```
Map<String, Integer> wordsToIdMap = new HashMap<>();
```

In order to fill the map:

```
    do {
        String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("word"));

        // Unsure about this line, change it as needed:
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")); 

        wordsToIdMap.put(word, id);
    } while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

Now you can get the `id` by doing a super fast call like this:

```
 int id = wordsToIdMap.get(word);
```

Comment: Tnxx for the explanation Sir...That was really beneficial.Just the last query.Where do I put the last line i.e. int id = wordsToIdMap.get(word);

Comment: I would put that where you call the dbBackend for dictionary words.  Make a method in dbbackend that accepts a word and then gets it from the wordsToIdMap.